# unable to map entity with composite @IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have the following model (a very simplified version of a much bigger model)

```
public enum EntityType {
    DOG, HAMMER
}

@Entity
public class Entity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityKey key;
    private String someProp;
}

@Embeddable
public class EntityKey implements Serializable{
    private Long serial;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EntityType type;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(MetricKey.class)
public class Metric {
    @Id
    private EntityKey entityKey;
    @Id
    private Long timestamp;
    private Double sampledValue;
}

public class MetricKey implements Serializable {
    private EntityKey entityKey;
    private Long timestamp;
}
```

Entity in reality is an abstract class at the root of a large hierarchy. Metric represents some data sampled on an entity at a particular point in time. Entity has a composite key consisting of type and serial number, and metric should have a composite key consisting of the entity key + timestamp.

the above code gets me this exception from hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [serial] not found on Metric
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:166)
    ... 45 more
```

it looks like it spotted the `@Embeddable` on EntityKey and is trying to break it apart here as well.

i know i can work around this by making MetricKey `@Embeddable` and rewriting some code:

```
@Entity
public class Metric {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MetricKey key;
    private Double sampledValue;
}
@Embeddable
public class MetricKey implements Serializable{
    private EntityKey entityKey;
    private Long timeStamp;
}
```

but i'd much prefer the original design, since `EntityKey` is widely used across the system and having to convert back and forth between `EntityKey` and `MetricKey` would annoy developers.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution for I can propose you is changing the implementation of `Metric` to

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MetricKey.class)
public class Metric {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity entity;
    @Id
    private Long timestamp;
    private Double sampledValue;
}
```

You can also consult *2.4.1.1 Specification of Derived Identities* of the JPA 2.1 spec.

> If an Id attribute in the entity is a many-to-one or one-to-one relationship to a parent
>   entity, the corresponding attribute in the id class must be of the same Java type as the
>   id class or embedded id of the parent entity (if the parent entity has a composite primary
>   key) or the type of the Id attribute of the parent entity (if the parent entity has a
>   simple primary key).

My solution was tested against Hibernate 4.3.6

Comment: as i expect to have a large number of Metric rows (millions?) that FK looks like a serious space (join table) / performance (fk lookup) issue. also, Entity is polymorphic which makes the lookup even worse.

Comment: Have thought about lazy loading?

Comment: yes, but there will still be a costly lookup @insertion time, especially given that Entity is abstract and with ~50 subclasses, not sharing a table.